# Dummy value output by Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, image-processing

I am passing the structure pointer to function and accessing it in function but the pointer points to dummy value after the it enters this function.

Here is the code that read pixel values

```
#define MAX_SIZE 50000
void readImage(Image * img)
{
    int pixels[MAX_SIZE];
    int a =0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            pixels[a] = image.at<uchar>(i, j);
            a++;
        }
    }
    (*img).data = pixels;
}
```

The structure is as follows:

```
struct Image {
        int *data;
    };
```

In main i am passing this Structure object to another function after reading:

```
int main()
{
 Image img;
 readImage(&img);

 std::cout << *(*img).data; // this prints first pixel value i.e. 0

 test(&img);
 return 0;
}
```

In Test function i am accessing it as follows -

```
void test(Image * img)
{
 std::cout << *(*img).data;
}
```

This prints the output as -858993460
but if print the same thing in main it outputs 0

Are there any errors in above method I want the Test function to output same as in main()

Note :- Ignore indentation/syntax errors if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating pixel information some memory from `readImage()` function. This is okay.

The problem lies in the fact that you are assigning this to `img` variable  which is a pointer. `img` stores the address of `pixels` variable, which is allocated on stack. But as soon as this function goes out of scope, it is no longer accessible. But since you assigned this to `img` and are trying to access it outside this function, you are receiving **garbage** value in it.

The solution to this lies that you should allocate memory to `pixels` in heap. So instead of doing:

```
int pixels[MAX_SIZE];
```

Allocate it on heap, using:

```
int *pixels = (int *)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(int));
```

or using `new` like this:

```
int *pixels = new int[MAX_SIZE];
```

Just be careful to use `free` if using `malloc` and `delete []` when using `new`

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with `int pixels[MAX_SIZE];` inside the `readImage` function. It is allocated on the stack, and will be released when call returns. You have to allocate on heap using the `new` operator.

Comment: Using new do i need to declare structure inside readImage function()

Comment: No. Just replace `int pixels[MAX_SIZE];` with: `int *pixels = new int[MAX_SIZE];`